# UI5 Message box customize Button

Tags: sapui5

I need help to update button (OK) text on Message box I am using library `sap.ca.ui.message`

```
sap.ca.ui.message.showMessageBox({
    type: sap.ca.ui.message.Type.ERROR,
    message: "Erro Text Message",
}, function(){});
```

How can I access the button in the message box. Basically I'm looking from a translation perspective. Here in this message box I am able to translate title and message text, but I am unable to translate the *OK button* text.

Comment: `sap.ca.ui.message` is deprecated since 1.28, you should switch to `sap.m.MessageBox`. Also, all text that is included in a predefined control should already be translated by the SAPUI5 team. Which language are you using?

Comment: https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/explored.html?sap-language=ET#/sample/sap.m.sample.MessageBox/preview here I am using langudge Estonia if you check diffrant message box example title text and message is tranlated also Close and Cancel buttons but not able to change OK button text for any language

Answer (score 2):

There is actually a new solution available now allowing you to create your custom action button by renaming the close button to something else.
(**"Manage Products"** in this example).

This is the snippet from the UI5 Messagebox Samples.

```
MessageBox.error( "Product A does not exist.",
    {
        actions: ["Manage Products", sap.m.MessageBox.Action.CLOSE],
        styleClass: bCompact ? "sapUiSizeCompact" : "",
        onClose: function(sAction) {
            MessageToast.show("Action selected: " + sAction);
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comments, `sap.ca.ui.message` is deprecated since 1.28. It is recommended to use the `sap.m.MessageBox`.

However, the `sap.m.MessageBox` currently does not allow custom actions (buttons) and icons (titles).

There is a predefined set of supported actions (see `sap.m.MessageBox.Action`) and titles (see `sap.m.MessageBox.Icon`). These actions are already translated, you can take a look at the Estonian translations here (look for the Strings that start with `MSGBOX_`): https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.m/src/sap/m/messagebundle_et.properties

If you think that the translation is wrong or that there is a better translation, you can make a new pull request with your own translation or simply open a ticket here: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues

Comment: Thanks Marc for looking into query.
When I update some Text keys in i18n_et.properties file i.e.
                   WARNING =Hoiatus ,
                   ERROR =Viga ,
                   SUCCESSFUL =Edukas ,
                   CANCEL=Katkesta ,
change reflect in message box except OK button so is there any other way I can access OK text and  implement Translation change

Comment: Afaik you have to modify the `messagebundle_et.properties`. That means you have to modify the SDK directly. Therefore I suggested opening a ticket. What is the correct translation btw?

Comment: No I didn't modify any file yet that file I work on app translation  version so just update i18n_et.properties(on i18n langudge folder) file doing this all other app text is update also some default fiori key like ERROR , CANCEL changed but not OK key just checking at other way I can able to update/override text key it.  I am trying some javascript here but hard luck

Comment: But in [fiori message box guideline](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/ui-components/message-box/) , it needs `Leave Page`, `Approve` which is not in the [sap.m.Action](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.m.MessageBox.Action.html)

Comment: Fixed my issue by using `sap.m.Dialog`

Answer (score 0):

the translation texts are in a resource bundle and you can alter the value accordingly. like this

```
sap.ui.define(["sap/m/Button", "sap/m/MessageBox"], function(Button, MessageBox) {
  var rb = sap.ui.getCore().getLibraryResourceBundle("sap.m");
  rb.aPropertyFiles[0].mProperties["MSGBOX_YES"] = "OOO";
  rb.aPropertyFiles[0].mProperties["MSGBOX_CANCEL"] = "Katkesta";

  var oButton = new Button({
    text: "Press",
    press: function() {

      MessageBox.show("This message should appear in the message box.", {
        icon: MessageBox.Icon.INFORMATION,
        title: "My message box title",
        actions: [MessageBox.Action.YES, MessageBox.Action.CANCEL],
        onClose: function(oAction) {
        }
      });
    }
  });
  oButton.placeAt("content");
});
```

https://jsbin.com/qumiweg/edit?js,output